# How to remove an element from a list by user input in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, user-input

I want to remove an element from a list by using a user input and a for loop.

This is as far I got:

```
patientname = input("Enter the name of the patient: ") 
for x in speclistpatient_peter:                
    del speclistpatient_peter
```

Comment: Presumably `speclistpatient_peter` is a list of names, all strings?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `remove` method for lists:

```
 l = ["ab", "bc", "ef"]
 l.remove("bc")
```

removes the elment `"bc"` from `l`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension; altering a list in a `for` loop while looping can lead to problems as the list size changes and indices shift up:

```
speclistpatient_peter = [x for x in speclistpatient_peter if x != patientname]
```

This rebuilds the list but leaves out the elements that match the entered `patientname` value.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
patientname = input("Enter the name of the patient: ")
```

Putting anything in the `input()` function rather than the specific thing you want to delete or find from the list will cause an error. In your case you added `("Enter the name of the patient: ")`, so after the execution it will search for **"Enter the name of the patient: "** in the list but its not there.

Here is how you can delete a specific item from the list. You don't have use loop, instead you can delete it by using the `remove()` function:

```
print("Enter the item you want to delete")
patientname = input() # Dont Put anything between the first bracket while using input()
speclistpatient_peter.remove(patientname)
print(speclistpatient_peter)
```

Comment: Actually, it will not. `input` is very special in python, and the argument inside `input` is the prompt. You could run this in IDLE or any other REPL.

Answer (score 0):

```py
print("Enter the item you want to delete")
patientname = input() # Dont Put anything between the first bracket while using input()
speclistpatient_peter.remove(patientname)
print(speclistpatient_peter)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow! Please try to markdown your code and explain about your code for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a certain element:
speclstpatient_peter.remove('name')

---

If the array contains 2x the same element and you only want the firstm this will not work. Most dynamic is just a counter instead of a pointer:

```
x=0
while x<len(speclistpatient_peter):
    if speclistpatient_peter[x].find(something):   # or any if statement  
         del(speclistpatien_peter[x])
    else:
         x=x+1
```

---

or make a function to keep it readable:

```
def erase(text, filter):
    return [n for n in text if n.find(filter)<0] 

a = ['bart', 'jan']
print erase(a, 'rt')
```